# System Simulation - RNG full period linear congruential generator

Tags: random

How do I know if the following statement is a full period linear congruential generator: rng(I)=(5*I)mod 7

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be full cycle because a seed of 0 yields fixed-point behavior.  It produces all 6 strictly positive outcomes though.

Here's a demonstration in Ruby:

```
class Doh
  attr_reader :seed

  def initialize(seed)
    @seed = seed
  end

  def next
    @seed *= 5
    @seed %= 7
  end
end

rng = Doh.new(1)
puts Array.new(7) { rng.next }.join(', ')  # produces 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 5
rng2 = Doh.new(0)
puts Array.new(7) { rng2.next }.join(', ') # produces 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```